# How to combine an effect like scaling w/ fadeOut in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I wish to make an object fade out and scale down 80% at the same time.

This is what I tried which is not correct because the animations happen in sequence instead of at the same time.

```
$div.effect("scale", {percent:80, origin:['middle','center']}, 3000);
$div.fadeOut(3000, function()
{
   //Animation done
});
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.animate()` function.
Here there are some examples that can fit your needs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I'm tempted to post some working code, but I think that OP will benefit from experimenting on his/her own.

Comment: OK, thanks. I see how animate can be made to do it once I calc the final position values.